# Finding the vertex coordinates of a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I should know this, but how do I find the values of the vertex coordinates of a graph which is laid out automatically?

Answer (score 5):

The [`GraphEmbedding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphEmbedding.html) function. ${}$

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you, my memory fails me once again:( !

Comment: It is strange, I do a lot of graphs and networks programming, and yet I forget basic things sometimes!!

Comment: @EGME, `AbsoluteOptions[graph, VertexCoordinates]` also works in earlier versions.

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon Thank you!